# R Plotting confidence bands with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a confidence band for a model fitted with gls like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(nlme)

mp <-data.frame(year=c(1990:2010))

mp$wav <- rnorm(nrow(mp))*cos(2*pi*mp$year)+2*sin(rnorm(nrow(mp)*pi*mp$wav))+5
mp$wow <- rnorm(nrow(mp))*mp$wav+rnorm(nrow(mp))*mp$wav^3

m01 <- gls(wow~poly(wav,3), data=mp, correlation = corARMA(p=1))

mp$fit <- as.numeric(fitted(m01))

p <- ggplot(mp, aes(year, wow))+ geom_point()+ geom_line(aes(year,fit))
p
```

This only plots the fitted values and the data, and I would like something in the style of

```
p <- ggplot(mp, aes(year, wow))+ geom_point()+ geom_smooth()
p
```

but with the bands generated by the gls model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(nlme)

set.seed(101)
mp <-data.frame(year=1990:2010)
N <- nrow(mp)

mp <- within(mp,
         {
             wav <- rnorm(N)*cos(2*pi*year)+rnorm(N)*sin(2*pi*year)+5
             wow <- rnorm(N)*wav+rnorm(N)*wav^3
         })

m01 <- gls(wow~poly(wav,3), data=mp, correlation = corARMA(p=1))
```

Get fitted values (the same as `m01$fitted`)

```
fit <- predict(m01)
```

Normally we could use something like `predict(...,se.fit=TRUE)` to get the confidence intervals on the prediction, but `gls` doesn't provide this capability.  We use a recipe similar to the one shown at http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq :

```
V <- vcov(m01)
X <- model.matrix(~poly(wav,3),data=mp)
se.fit <- sqrt(diag(X %*% V %*% t(X)))
```

Put together a "prediction frame":

```
predframe <- with(mp,data.frame(year,wav,
                                wow=fit,lwr=fit-1.96*se.fit,upr=fit+1.96*se.fit))
```

Now plot with `geom_ribbon`

```
(p1 <- ggplot(mp, aes(year, wow))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line(data=predframe)+
    geom_ribbon(data=predframe,aes(ymin=lwr,ymax=upr),alpha=0.3))
```

[image: year vs wow]

It's easier to see that we got the right answer if we plot against `wav` rather than `year`:

```
(p2 <- ggplot(mp, aes(wav, wow))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line(data=predframe)+
    geom_ribbon(data=predframe,aes(ymin=lwr,ymax=upr),alpha=0.3))
```

[image: wav vs wow]

It would be nice to do the predictions with more resolution, but it's a little tricky to do this with the results of `poly()` fits -- see `?makepredictcall`.

Comment: How might you make the polynomial of the last graph smooth and actually look like a polynomial?

Comment: As I said, that would be tricky. You have to make sure that you construct the model matrix in such a way that it uses the basis from the original model - see `?makepredictcall`.