# How to use the data argument of a formula function?

Tags: r, least-squares

My code is:

```
gls(fish~data+temp+size, na.action=na.omit, data=???, correlation=corAR1(form=~Date))
```

I just want to know about the `data` argument because I have no idea what to put in it. I understand it is the variables of the `gls` but I don't exactly get what that translates to when using the formula.

I've tred looking at the manuals but it doesn't give me much more than its the variables of the `gls` which I suppose sounds obvious unless you've never done it before.

Comment: An example of use would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033551/r-plotting-confidence-bands-with-ggplot

Answer (score 4):

The `data` argument refers to the data.frame from which the variables in your formula are supposed to be drawn. This is consistent across all modelling functions in R (see for example `? lm`; though you're not using a base package and haven't specified what package `gls` is coming from, so perhaps this is something different).

Comment: One possible source of `gls` would be `nlme` package where `data` argument is consistent with the rest of the modeling functions.

Comment: The data but can be used in other formula I just happen to be using gls. my problem was knowing what to put after the data=

Comment: model1<-gls(Number.of.Fish~Julian.Date+Temperature+Size.Class,na.action=na.omit,data=mydata,correlation=corAR1(form=~Julian.Date))    
Unfortunately still doesn't work. I keep getting an error message about the AR1:  Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[1L]], ...) : 
covariate must have unique values within groups for "corAR1" objects.                    I've found the other people trying to find the solution to this error but no one seems to know.

Comment: @Francesca That sounds like you should post that issue as a new question.