# Average histograms by class and plot with confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, visualization

I have a data frame `df` like this:

```
    x   series  no
1   24  u       3   
2   12  u       2
3   23  v       1
4   17  u       3
5   5   v       2
6   45  v       1
7   18  u       3
8   32  v       2
9   34  u       1
10  37  v       3
...
```

Here, `x` is the value being measured, `series` is the series the measurement belongs to, `no` is the number within that series.

I want to see how the distribution of values in `x` varies between and within `series`.

I can simply filter out each series/no on its own and plot them as different lines. The result would look like this:

[image]

Now you can see that within the series `u`, the variation is more in some places and less in other places. This is also the case with series `v`. I want to show this with confidence intervals, and get something like this:

[image]

Here the brown line is the average of lines u1, u2 and u3, and the pink area is the confidence interval. Likewise for light blue, dark blue and v1, v2, v3.

Of course the confidence interval would look slightly different because I carelessly drew this by hand, without calculating the actual CI, but hopefully my intent will be clear.

How can I accomplish this in R? Can I do the plot with `ggplot`?

Answer (score 0):

First graph involves grouping by two factors and can be plotted using `ggplot2`. Below is an example using `mpg` dataset in R. `cty` is a numerical variable and `drv` and `fl` are two categorical variables.

You will have to combine two factors first.

```
library(dplyr)
copy_mpg <- mpg
copy_mpg <- select(mpg, cty, drv, fl)
copy_mpg$df <- with(copy_mpg, interaction(drv, fl))
```

Plot: 
`ggplot(copy_mpg, aes(hwy, col=df)) + geom_density() + theme_bw()`

A shortcut: `ggplot(copy_mpg, aes(hwy, col=interaction(drv, fl))) + geom_density() + theme_bw()`

[image: Plot]
And for second part, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033551/r-plotting-confidence-bands-with-ggplot) SO question and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49835/how-does-ggplot-compute-confidence-intervals-for-regressions) Stats question.